# Convert an array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How do I make this output to a string?

```
List<string> Client = new List<string>();
foreach (string listitem in lbClients.SelectedItems)
{
    Client.Add(listitem);
}
```

Comment: What type of string? Delimiter separated?

Comment: What do you want the resulting string to look like?

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using? The suggested String.Join() overload was added in .NET 4, before which the method only took an Array.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can join your array using the following:

```
string.Join(",", Client);
```

Then you can output anyway you want. You can change the comma to what ever you want, a space, a pipe, or whatever.

Answer (score 17):

You probably want something like this overload of String.Join:

`String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)`

Docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

In your example, you'd use

`String.Join("", Client);`

Answer (score 10):

My suggestion:

```
using System.Linq;

string myStringOutput = String.Join(",", myArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
```

reference:
https://coderwall.com/p/oea7uq/convert-simple-int-array-to-string-c

Comment: Your answer is functionally no different to the others. [`string.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) already calls `ToString()` on the items, and there is a [`string.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) method that doesn't need the `ToArray()`.

Comment: Selecting the list element and converting to string avoids the ambiguity in different data types.

Answer (score 10):

You can write like this:

```cs
string[] arr = { "Miami", "Berlin", "Hamburg"};
string s = string.Join(" ", arr);
```