# Nhibernate concatenate list string result

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a little problem. I want concatenate a list of string in a nhibernate query.

For example, i have a list of string `("A", "B", "C")`, I want concatenate this in only one string `"A,B,C"`.
Is it possible?

This is my Query:

```
IQCategory.Select(x => new ResultModel 
  { Id = x.Id, 
    Category = x.Category, 
    ArticleOfCategory = x.ListArticle.Select(y=>y.Description).ToString() 
  });
```

Comment: `String.Join(",", yourList)`? http://stackoverflow.com/q/799446/447156

Comment: I doubt that there is a good way to do it in LINQ query. In any case you won't win much by doing it on the server side, so just [String.Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426463/convert-array-to-string-c-sharp) the result.

Comment: Thank's Soner! It's Perfect!